# memory high issue on RHEL server?

Tags: linux, memory, redhat

```
18105 /wm/www/tmmy/              2.2 1128256 1683020
16961 /usr/sbin/httpd              2.4 1201668 1692788
27746 /usr/sbin/httpd              2.4 1217296 1701612
31519 /usr/sbin/httpd              2.4 1223532 1710176
18192 /wm/www/tmmy/              2.5 1279708 1792296
13275 /wm/www/tmmy/              2.6 1295352 1784484
18110 /wm/www/tmmy/              2.6 1298748 1824332
18111 /wm/www/tmmy/              2.6 1311296 1830760
18109 /usr/sbin/httpd              2.7 1369940 1877280
18417 /wm/www/tmmy/              2.8 1436096 1986728
```

This is output of `ps` command of top few processes eating memory on RHEL server Is there a way to know what exact file is being rendered by `httpd` process so that I can find out what leading to memory spike?

Comment: What about the access logs?

Comment: access_log doesn't gives exact details .....

Comment: use strace -p [httpd pid] it may give some hints

Comment: What îs the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`?

Answer (score 0):

You might also try lsof ("list open files").  There are methods for specifying what you want to see e.g. only things with TCP connections, only things in a specific process or a specific directory, etc.

It only gives you what is happening at that moment in time, but if something is chewing that up by itself, it should be able to point you in the right direction.